# Good way to detect identical expressions in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a program that solves this puzzle game: some numbers and a goal number is given, and you make the goal number using the n numbers and operators +, -, *, / and (). For example, given 2,3,5,7 and the goal number 10, the solutions are `(2+3)*(7-5)=10`, `3*5-(7-2)=10`, and so on.

The catch is, if I implement it naively, I will get a bunch of identical solutions, like `(2+3)*(7-5)=10` and `(3+2)*(7-5)=10`, and `3*5-(7-2)=10` and `5*3-(7-2)=10` and `3*5-7+2=10` and `3*5+2-7=10` and so on. So I'd like to detect those identical solutions and prune them.

I'm currently using randomly generated double numbers to detect identical solutions. What I'm doing is basically substituting those random numbers to the solution and check if there are any pairs of them that calculate to the same number. I have to perform the detection at every node of my search, so it has to be fast, and I use hashset for it now.

Now the problem is the error that comes with the calculation. Because even identical solutions do not calculate to the exactly same value, I currently round the calculated value to a precision when storing in the hashset. However this does not seem to work well enough, and gives different number of solutions every time to the same problem. Sometimes the random numbers are bad and prune some completely different solutions. Sometimes the calculated value lies on the edge of rounding function and it outputs two(or more) identical solutions. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
By "identical" I mean two or more solutions(f(w,x,y,z,...) and g(w,x,y,z,...)) that calculate to the same number whatever the original number(w,x,y,z...) is. For more examples, 4/3*1/2 and 1*4/3/2 and (1/2)/(3/4) are identical, but 4/3/1/2 and 4/(3*1)/2 are not because if you change 1 to some other number they will not produce the same result.

Comment: Since your problem is framed in integers it seems perverse to be using doubles to implement a solution.  Equality comparison of calculated doubles is a subtle and engaging topic but one that, if you are not well-versed, may be confusing and troubling.  What confuses and troubles me is why you are using doubles at all.

Comment: How do you generate the expressions? You could simply generate candidates in such a way that you won't get duplicates. The problems you show have to do with *commutativity* of addition and multiplication. You can simply implement some extra logic to ensure the LHS is always less than or equal to the RHS. Then the only way you will get duplicates of the kind you seem to not want is if you have duplicate numbers in your list of numbers, and in this case, you will get identical expressions and can use string equality to detect and eliminate them.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I'm using double because I have to handle divisions correctly. I don't know how I should do divisions with two random int numbers(I could do division modulo p, but it is O(logn) and I think will be the performance killer)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark By the way there are also problems that you MUST use fractions to solve. One example is 1,1,9,9 and goal=10, which the only solution is (1+1/9)*9=10.

Comment: You are missing something.  There are infinite solutions if you cannot define what identical means.  2-3-(4-5) = 2-3-4+5, yet it seems the same to me.  You can also put in infinite () and + symbols.  (eg. (((((2-3-4+5))))) and 2-3-4+(+5).

Comment: Maybe [expression trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) can help.

Comment: @eronaut It was implied (probably should have been stated) in the original problem that if you substitute W, X, Y and Z for the four numbers, two expressions are the same if any algebraic transformation brings them together.  But if two are the same only because of the four specific values, they are not the same.

Comment: @Patrick87 I generate candidates by picking two numbers, doing some operation on them, and putting back to the pool. The LHS<=RHS rule does not eliminate those like 2+(3+4), 4+(2+3), 3+(2+4).

Comment: @eivour What if you combine it with another rule that you only ever use parentheses if they change the value of the expression? Since none of the parentheses you show in your counterexamples are required, this rule would eliminate all of those sorts of things. More generally - is there some small fixed set of "rules" you can use to - as John Zwinck wisely advises - canonicalize your expressions? That is the smart money. Also, I would recommend you avoid doubles at all costs. I'd implement my own "rational number" class before using doubles for something like this.

Comment: @JSF Thanks, I edited the question and included the meaning of "identical".

Comment: @Patrick87 I don't think writing the operations between all the numbers and try using parentheses if it "changes something" is a good approach to this problem because I would have to try all the ordering of the numbers, generating more identical solutions(there are solutions that you cannot reach by fixing the order of numbers and only using parenthesis, while there are also solutions that you cannot reach by only changing the order of numbers without using parenthesis). I liked the idea of "rational class" though. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Divisions take you to the world of rational numbers, fractions as you put it.   And note that games such as the one you outline frequently allow only divisions with integral results so `4/2` but not `4/3`.

Comment: You could use modulo arithmetic instead of rationals. The theory is Schwartz--Zippel; pick a large prime modulus and you should be all set.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I will try it out, but I'm concerned about the performance. Even with my current method it takes about 15s to solve a problem with 7 numbers. I suppose it will take about 30x as long as a single double division(if using full 32bit prime in order to avoid collision).

Answer (score 8):

It will be easier if you "canonicalize" the expressions before comparing them.  One way would be to sort when an operation is commutative, so `3+2` becomes `2+3` whereas `2+3` remains as it was.  Of course you will need to establish an ordering for parenthesized groups as well, like `3+(2*1)`...does that become `(1*2)+3` or `3+(1*2)`?  What the ordering is doesn't necessarily matter, so long as it is a total ordering.

Comment: "canonicalize" is the usual answer to this kind of question and it MAY be the right answer this time.  But it is far harder than you imply.  The original question implies 3*5+(2-7) is the "same" answer as 3*5-7+2.  It is far from obvious how you canonicalize all the rules needed to cover things like that.  Just knowing 3*5 is the "right" way to write 5*3 only scratches the surface.

Comment: Where do you draw the line though? Is `3*5+(2-7)` the same as `10`?

Comment: @orlp Rephrasing what eivour added already to the original post:  F(3,5,2,7)=G(3,5,2,7) necessarily or they would not be candidate solutions.  But if F(W,X,Y,Z)=G(W,X,Y,Z) for all W,X,Y,Z then F(3,5,2,7) and G(3,5,2,7) are considered the "same" solution.

Comment: I think canonicalizing is a good way if you want to simplify a single expression or check overlappings of a medium number of expressions(like a thousand or ten thousand), but I have much more expressions to deal with. Without pruning I get up to tens of millions of solutions, and I don't think canonicalizing all of them (or even simply keeping proper expression tree for all of them) is practical. I currently prune many candidates in early stage using fast (but inaccurate) randomized algorithm, but if I had to canonicalize all the intermediate expressions......it's getting out of my hand.

Comment: @eivour, what you just said seems exactly backwards.  Canonicalizing expression trees would take a significant amount of thought and probably a significant amount of code (compared to using doubles or a rational class and random inputs).  But then it would have no disadvantage (probably a big advantage) in performance if you are working with a very large number of candidate expressions.  You would keep proper expression trees only for the unique ones.

Comment: Side issue:  Are the original N numbers unique and if not, what does that do to the rules?  If your input numbers were 2, 4, and 4 I expect you want A*B+C to be treated as the same as A*C+B, as both are 2*4+4.  But that goes against the basic definition of sameness.  So I hope original numbers must be unique.  Otherwise that special case distorts the whole design.  Instead of seeing F(X,Y,Z) you would want to see F(X,Y) being defined as an expression using Y twice.

Comment: @eivour: rather than your inaccurate, randomized solution to prune early, why not just canonicalize immediately as part of generation?  Then you can always compare against the smaller set of canonical solutions, and never store the complete set of redundant ones.  For example, when generating solutions you should never allow unsorted commutative pieces such as `3*2`, instead you would only allow `2*3`.

Comment: @JohZwinck if you canonicalize correctly, there is no need to store even the non redundant ones.  Best would be generate canonical and never see the non  canonical, cases.  But even if you need to canonicalize after generating, it is easy to know whether you changed the structure by canonicalizing (in which case you can simply discard this case knowing the canonical version will be or has been generated).  Saving and comparing canonical forms is either not necessary or not good enough, in this problem.  In other problems it is a common technique.

Answer (score 2):

Generate all possibilities of your expressions.  Then..
When you create expressions, put them in a collection of parsed trees (this would also eliminate your parenthesis).  Then "push down" any division and subtraction into the leaf nodes so that all the non-leaf nodes have * and +.  Apply a sorting of the branches (e.g. regular string sort) and then compare the trees to see if they are identical.

Comment: How do you "push down" the division in `(A+B)/(C+D)` ?  I think you are correct that subtraction can be eliminated in favor of negation and negation can be pushed down.  But even that takes care `(-A)*B` vs. `A*(-B)`.  Expression trees are easier to canonicalize than strings.  But even in the limited subset of expressions, there are a lot of details.

Comment: You can't push down the division any further in that expression.  You would have to figure out what the rule is to "flip" expressions with a double division (eg. a/b/(c/d).)

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using doubles.  The problem is in the rounding.  Why not use a container SORTED by the value obtained with one random set of double inputs.  When you find the place you would insert in that container, you can look at the immediately preceding and following items.  Use a different set of random doubles to recompute each for the more robust comparison.  Then you can have a reasonable cutoff for "close enough to be equal" without arbitrary rounding.

If a pair of expressions are close enough for equal in both the main set of random numbers and the second set, the expressions are safely "same" and the newer one discarded.  If close enough for equal in the main set but not the new set, you have a rare problem, that probably requires rekeying the entire container with a different random number set.  If not close enough in either, then they are different.

Comment: I just want to say "WOW" to whoever down voted this a second after I posted it. You clearly reacted only to the first sentence without even reading the whole idea. You also know far less about the topic, because it is a more common topic than you might think and using random doubles is a common solution. Using integers is a broken idea and canonicalizing is much harder than it is worth.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate your idea (I couldn't understand it enough to either upvote or downvote). How is it better than using rational numbers?

Comment: @anatolyg I think this is a good idea. One problem with rational numbers is that it does not work well with random integers. (It overflows soon when adding two fractions with large but different denominators. I could limit the random numbers to be below 2^10 but then I'm afraid I would have the problem of collision.) Using random doubles and a sorted set avoids this problem.

Comment: @anatolg  I think the idea was clear enough.  Nailing down every detail was not the point of that answer.  Part of the point was that random doubles is likely the best comparison method, better than either rational numbers or canonical, because each of those is far more complicated (once you remember overflow issues in rational numbers).  The key concept is that rounding was the real problem in the OP's original try.  Comparing with a tolerance is easy and reliable.  Rounding before doing an exact comparison may seem similar, but is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: I stand by my first answer that doubles is the best comparison method.  Canonical is a rotten comparison method for this problem.  **But** canonical by construction (which is very different from canonical comparison) is the most efficient approach to the wider problem, and worth the extra coding time when N is larger.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with integers, I'd focus on getting an exact result.

**Claim:** Suppose there is some f(a_1, ..., a_n) = x where a_i and x are your integer input numbers and f(a_1, ..., a_n) represents any functions of your desired form. Then clearly f(a_i) - x = 0. I claim, we can construct a different function g with g(x, a_1, ..., a_n) = 0 for the exact same x and g only uses ()s, +, - and * (no division).

I'll prove that below. Consequently you could construct g evaluate g(x, a_1, ..., a_n) = 0 on integers only.

**Example:**
Suppose we have a_i = i for i = 1, ..., 4 and f(a_i) = a_4 / (a_2 - (a_3 / 1)) (which contains divisions so far). This is how I would like to simplify:

```
0 = a_4 / (a_2 - (a_3 / a_1) ) - x          | * (a_2 - (a_3 / a_1) )
0 = a_4 -       x * (a_2 - (a_3 / a_1) )    | * a_1
0 = a_4 * a_1 - x * (a_2 * a_1 - (a_3) )
```

In this form, you can verify your equality for some given integer x using integer operations only.

---

**Proof:**
There is some g(x, a_i) := f(a_i) - x which is equivalent to f. Consider any equivalent g with as few as possible division. Assume there is at least one (otherwise we are done). Assume within g we divide by h(x, a_i) (any of your functions, may contain divisions itself). Then (g*h)(x, a_i) := g(x, a_i) * h(x, a_i) has the same roots, as g has (multiplying by a root, ie. (x, a_i) where g(a_i) - x = 0, preserves all roots). But on the other hand, g*h is composed of one division fewer. A contradiction (g with minimum number of divisions), which is why g doesn't contain any division.

I've updated the example to visualize the strategy.

**Update:** This works well on rational input numbers (those represent a single division p/q). This should help you. Other input can't be provided by humans.

What are you doing to find / test f's? I'd guess some form of dynamic programming will be fast in practice.

Comment: That's great, but then I will have to substitute some random integer in the place of 1,2,3,4 and solve for x to check equality. And the problem that solved x might be a rational number still remains.
Another way to check for equality is to compare the expression tree, but I think it will be at least as tough as canonicalizing.

Comment: I thought, x would be input too. Sure, it only works for integer x. I just wanted to share this trick, as I liked it.

Comment: Well, it would be useful if if f(a,b,c,d)=g(a,b,c,d)=x, the transformed functions F(a,b,c,d,x)=0 and G(a,b,c,d,x)=0 will have the property that for any number a,b,c,d,x F(a,b,c,d,x)=G(a,b,c,d,x). I don't think it's true though...because when G(a,b,c,d,x)=2*F(a,b,c,d,x), f(a,b,c,d) still equals g(a,b,c,d) when solved for x.

Answer (score 0):

For the larger `n` suggested by one of your recent comments, I think you would need the better performance that should be possible from a canonical by construction method (or maybe "almost" canonical by construction) rather than a primarily comparison based approach.

You **don't** want to construct an incredibly large number of expressions, then canonicalize and compare.

Define a doubly recursive function can(...) that takes as input:
A reference to a canonical expression tree.
A reference to one subexpression of that tree.
A count N of inputs to be injected.
A set of flags for prohibiting some injections.
A leaf function to call.

If N is zero, `can` just calls the leaf function.  If N is nonzero, `can` patches the subtree in every possible way that produces a canonical tree with N injected variables, and calls the leaf function for each and restores the tree, undoing each part of the patch as it is done with it, so we never need massive copying.

X is the subtree and K is a leaf representing variable N-1.  First `can` would replace the subtree temporarily one at a time with subtrees representing some of `(X)+K`, `(X)-K`, `(X)*K`, `(X)/K` and `K/(X)` but both flags and some other rules would cause some of those to be skipped.  For each not skipped, recursively call itself with the whole tree as both top and sub, with N-1, and with 0 flags.
Next drill into the two children of X and call recursively itself with that as the subtree, with N, and with appropriate flags.

The outer just calls `can` with a single node tree representing variable N-1 of the original N, and passing N-1.

In discussion, it is easier to name the inputs forward, so `A` is input N-1 and `B` is input N-2 etc.

When we drill into X and see it is `Y+Z` or `Y-Z` we don't want to add or subtract K from Y or Z because those are redundant with `X+K` or `X-K`.  So we pass a flag that suppresses direct add or subtract.

Similarly, when we drill into X and see it is `Y*Z` or `Y/Z` we don't want to multiply or divide either Y or Z by K because that is redundant with multiplying or dividing X by K.

Some cases for further clarification:

`(A/C)/B` and `A/(B*C)` are easily non canonical because we prefer `(A/B)/C` and so when distributing C into (A/B) we forbid direct multiplying or dividing.

I think it takes just a bit more effort to allow `C/(A*B)` while rejecting `C/(A/B)` which was covered by `(B/A)*C`.

It is easier if negation is inherently non canonical, so level 1 is just `A` and does not include `-A` then if the whole expression yields negative the target value, we negate the whole expression.  Otherwise we never visit the negative of a canonical expression:

Given X, we might visit (X)+K, (X)-K, (X)*K, (X)/K and K/(X) and we might drill down into the parts of X passing flags which suppress some of the above cases for the parts:

If X is a `+` or `-` suppress '+' or '-' in its direct parts.  If X is a `*` or `/` suppress `*` or divide in its direct parts.

But if X is a `/` we also suppress `K/(X)` before drilling into X.